# Version Control with java program, using DOS command

Tags: java, version-control, command

I'm trying to do something maybe foolish, and I need your help to clarify things.

Someone asked me how to handle versions of a firmware, so I told him about git, svn and all the GUI that come with these two things.
But it is not exactly what he needs. He is the onlyone to work on this firmware, and he only needs to handle the different versions. For example if he works on the v3, he wants to be able to come back to the former version at any time. Simultaneously, he wants to see the modifications like with the "git diff" command.

To give the program he wants, I'm trying to write a java program (maybe it's not the best choice?), that will use some of the git commands he needs (commit, diff, reset,...) and that will also provide the additionnal functionnalities he needs.

If you have suggestion or if I miss something, please tell me.

Now, about the java program:

I'm experiencing some trouble with the "git diff" command. In the shell, no problem I got all the red and green lines, but in the java console, nothing is displayed.
You should also know that the "git status" (for example) command works perfectly in both the shell and the java console.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a git command");
String command = keyboard.nextLine();
keyboard.close();
File execute = new File("C:/.../MyGitRepository");

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, execute);

Scanner s = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  text.append(s.nextLine());
  text.append("\n");
}
s.close();
int result = process.waitFor();

System.out.printf("Process exited with result %d and output %s%n", result, text );
```

With the "git diff" command, I get this:

```
enter a git command
git diff
```

And with the "git status" command I get this:

```
enter a git command
git status
Process exited with result 0 and output On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified: MyFile1.xml
modified: MyFile2.xml
modified: MyFile3.xml
...
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: He is the onlyone to work on this firmware, and he only needs to handle the different versions. 

in this statement, I see no reason whatsoever not to use svn (or an existing alternative). if he also needs to go for complete versions, maybe Maven can be of some help ?

Comment: Why wouldn't he just use Git normally? Why are you creating some sort of horrible wrapper around it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Stultuske, but I see on the official site, that Maven is for any Java-Based project. Maybe it was not clear, but the firmware in question is not in java, it is in C and consists in other files (.c, .h, .xml, ...). So Maven may not be the best solution ?

Comment: @Kayaman, this guy is not a developer an he doesn't understand how Git works. With a GUI and a specific documentation it could be ok, but he also needs to get back to any version at any time...

Comment: If it's not a developer, what does he do with the firmware?

Comment: @Raffaele he works for a company that gave him the software, he works in electronic and he is in charge of all the needed updates on the firmware.

Comment: Anyway, calling Git from Java is nonsense. The basic Git workflow is really easy to understand, and everybody can learn it, especially with a GUI frontend

Comment: git diff doesn't output anything unless there are unstaged modifications.

Answer (score 1):

If person in question haven't any previous experience with **any** VCS, then basing on Git is worst choice

For

> he wants to be able to come back to the former version at any time.
>   Simultaneously, he wants to see the modifications

which are the natural tasks for *any* SCM, he can select this ("any") VCS with good not overbloated GUI (for linear history even SVN|TortoiseSVN will be good choice)

Calling Git from Java is perversion, really

Comment: With the little information I have, I agree, but I don't see how he could be able to get any version of the code. For example, if there is a commit with the key "a1b2c3", and then several commit, it is not possible to get the corresponding version of the "a1b2c3" commit. And for this guy, it's a real problem.

Comment: Matthieu, you can do that operation, going back to a certain commit, with any really any version control system. You don't have to build any Java wrapper or anything. If you don't understand that statement, then I would suggest you to review any vcs (git, svn) and try to understand how it works. (Anyhow, you should understand it if you planned to build your Java wrapper....)